# Check item's position in my custom ListView made with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

My `ListView`is appearing great, it is loading news from a server and placing them in a `ListView`. So all i wanted to do is making the very latest new in another color but that's not working by checking: `if(position==0)` because **NOT ONLY** the **1st item** is having the layout modified to to my chosen color, but the **3rd** item too is having the layout changed. I don't know why the 3rd. Here below is my code:

```
 class simpleadapter extends SimpleAdapter
        {

            public simpleadapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                    int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
                super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                //final TextView tvTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                //final TextView tvContent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);


                final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl);

                if(position == 0)
                    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));//here 'im changing the layout 
holding the item in another color.

                rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                /*  tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Log.i(JohnMain,"Click on the Textview! Congrats!!!");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                 */
                return view;
                //          return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ListView`s recycle their row `View`s after they scroll off the screen (and aren't being used). So if you set the color of one row's `View`, and then it scrolls offscreen and gets recycled, it will still show the color you had set it to before, even though now it is in a different position. The general rule of thumb is to explicitly set every property of your row's `View` that is changed.

You just need an `else` statement in your code and to explicitly set the default color of each row.

```
 if(position == 0)
      rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
 else
      rl.setBackgroundColor(/*Default Color*/);
```

Comment: Thank you! your solution solved my problem! I would like to clarify that my 4th `item` is having the same color not the 3rd. So I should have edited my question. Any idea why the 4th not the 2nd item was having the `layout`'s color similar to the first one?

Comment: If my solution worked for you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. Also, if the 4th row was the first one you saw having the `#f0f0f0` color, it's because it was the first recycled `View`, aka the 4th `View` was added after the 1st `View` was off the screen, so the 4th row reused the 1st row (instead of creating a new one), so the recycled `View` showed the color you had set to it in the 1st row. Make sense?